# Facebook Developer App Review - Your submission must include pages_read_engagement to use instagram_basic

Tags: facebook, instagram-api, facebook-app-requests

Hello Facebook Developers Community,

I am trying to go through the 'Request for App Review' process for which I have completed all the steps besides one which is very confusing and literally has no useful guidance anywhere.

The dashboard shows visual checkmarks on all the steps completed besides the 'Your submission must include pages_read_engagement to use instagram_basic'

Just a brief background on what i am trying to do:
I am only trying to get the facebook developer access approved to go live to use 'Instagram Basic Display' and the api's to allow my application users to connect their instagram account and fetch only single images posted on their account to be displayed with in my application.

We have already gone through the 'Business Verification' process and already have that approved as well as having the facebook business account connect to our instagram account.

the only help i came across was on 'Pages Api' docs which mentions that

'The pages_read_engagement permission allows your app to read content (posts, photos, videos, events) posted by the Page, read followers data (including name, PSID), and profile picture, and read metadata and other insights about the Page. The allowed usage for this permission is to help a Page Admin administer and manage a Page. You may also use this permission to request analytics insights to improve your app and for marketing or advertising purposes, through the use of aggregated and de-identified or anonymized information (provided such data cannot be re-identified).'

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_engagement

for which none of those endpoints I am using or plan on using at all and not sure how it even got added.

I am really not sure what else to do and what pages_read_engagement has to do with my app to be approved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks